Set `body` `background-color` programmatically in Svelte?
I'm making a site using Svelte and SvelteKit, and I'd like to use a predefined array of colors for styling in a normalized way-- if I change one of the values later, everywhere that styles using that value will be updated later.
// palette.js

export const grays = [
  'hsl(240 3.7% 10.6%)',
  'hsl(240 13% 18%)',
  ...
];

// routes/+page.svelte

<script>
  import { grays } from '$lib/palette.js';
</script>

<div style="background-color: {grays[0]};">
  <i>stuff</i>
</div>

My problem is I can't figure out which is the best way to apply one of my colors to <body>.
Setting CSS values in a <style> tag like this:
<style>
  :global(body) {
    background-color: {grays[0]};
  }
</style>

is not valid syntax for Svelte (and using :global rules generally seems to be unidiomatic).
My current options (that I can think of) seem to be:

Set the document.body.style.backgroundColor in a <script>-- might cause flickering?
Don't style <body> at all, style a big <div> with a custom CSS property that covers everything (as shown in the Svlte tutorial)-- probably my best option but seems a bit ugly / smelly / boilerplatey to do all the var(...) and style="--customvar={grays[0]};.

What should I do? Am I overthinking this?

Why don't you define the colors in CSS instead?

Hi and thanks for your comment! Like just using custom CSS variables set on :root? That could totally work if I can reference those variables from other components, I'll look into that, thank you!

You can set CSS variables on the <html> element/:root and they will automatically be inherited to the rest of the application. A good place is the style of the root layout (src/routes/+layout.svelte) or a stylesheet imported from said layout.
<!-- +layout.svelte --->
<slot />
<style>
  :global(html) {
    --gray-1: ...;
    --gray-2: ...;
    --gray-3: ...;
    /* ... */

    background-color: var(--gray-1);
  }
</style>


<!-- +layout.svelte --->
<script>
  import './site.css';
</script>
<slot />

/* site.css */
html {
  --gray-1: ...;
  --gray-2: ...;
  --gray-3: ...;
  /* ... */

  background-color: var(--gray-1);
}


If for some reason the source of truth has to be some piece of JS, the most reliable way is probably to inject the values on build. I would still work with CSS variables, though.
You could e.g. generate the required CSS from the palette file via a custom Vite plugin.
/** @import { PluginOption } from 'vite' */

/**
 * A plugin that allows importing a generated CSS file from `@palette`.
 * @param {Record<string, string[]>} definitions
 *   Palette prefixes and the values for each palette.
 * @returns {PluginOption} The resulting plugin object.
 */
export function palettes(definitions) {
  const prefixedId = '/@palette/variables.css';

  return {
    name: 'palette-injector',
    resolveId(source) {
      if (source == '@palette')
        return prefixedId;
    },
    load(id) {
      if (id != prefixedId)
        return null;

      const css = Object.entries(definitions)
        .flatMap(([prefix, values]) =>
          values.map((value, i) => `--${prefix}-${i + 1}: ${value};`)
        )
        .join('\n');

      return {
        code: `:root { ${css} }`,
        map: null,
      };
    },
  }
}

// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { palettes } from './palettes-plugin';
import { grays } from './src/lib/palette';

export default defineConfig((cfg) => ({
  // ...
  plugins: [
    palettes({
      gray: grays,
    }),
    sveltekit(),
  ],
}));

<!-- +layout.svelte --->
<script>
  import '@palette';
</script>
<slot />
<style>
  :global(html) {
    background-color: var(--gray-1);
  }
</style>

